# Extract and transform values within a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like locate a certain pattern and then replace it with a new pattern. Example, **any value that contains: *2X6.4T*    , should be replaced with *12T,*** but ***not if it contains the 'word'  WOW***

**Data:**

```
Type

AY12-AYY-AY-R800-900G-2X6.4T_18T-R6-v.A
AY12-AYY-AY-R800-900G-2X6.4T_18T-R6-v.A
AY12-AYY-AY-R800-900G-2X6.4T_18T-R6-v.A
AY12-AYY-AY-R800XD-900G-6.4T-R11-WOW-v.A
AY12-AYY-AY-R800XD-900G-6.4T-R11-WOW-v.A
```

**Desired:**

```
Type

AY12-AYY-AY-R800-900G-12T_18T-R6-v.A
AY12-AYY-AY-R800-900G-12T_18T-R6-v.A
AY12-AYY-AY-R800-900G-12T_18T-R6-v.A
AY12-AYY-AY-R800XD-900G-6.4T-R11-WOW-v.A
AY12-AYY-AY-R800XD-900G-6.4T-R11-WOW-v.A
```

**Doing:**

```
df['Type'] = df['Type'].replace(['2X6.4T'],'12T')
```

However, this eliminates the full value of: *AY12-AYY-AY-R800-900G-2X6.4T_18T-R6-v.A* and not searching for and replacing.

Any suggestion is appreciated, I am still researching this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `np.where(condition, string if condition is true, string if condition false)`.For selection use `.str,contains()`

```
df['Type']=np.where(df['Type'].str.contains('2X6.4T')&~df['Type'].str.contains('WOW'),df['Type'].str.replace('2X6.4T','12T'),df['Type'])
print(df)
```

As suggested by @TrentonMcKinney, you can also use df.where;

```
df['Type']=df.where(df['Type'].str.contains('WOW'),df['Type'].str.replace('2X6.4T','12T'), axis=0)
                                  Type
0      AY12-AYY-AY-R800-900G-12T_18T-R6-v.A
1      AY12-AYY-AY-R800-900G-12T_18T-R6-v.A
2      AY12-AYY-AY-R800-900G-12T_18T-R6-v.A
3  AY12-AYY-AY-R800XD-900G-6.4T-R11-WOW-v.A
4  AY12-AYY-AY-R800XD-900G-6.4T-R11-WOW-v.A
```

Comment: There is also [`pandas.DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html), which removes the requirement of separately importing `numpy`.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney or `.mask`

Comment: Thanks @Trenton McKinney, good reminder. Will add the option

Comment: Nice one @David Erickson

Answer (score 1):

One option is `.mask`, which is what I usually use to make conditional changes to a column if the condition is on that column itself. That is because the default alternative is the existing column values.

```
df['Type'] =  df['Type'].mask(~df['Type'].str.contains('WOW'),
                              df['Type'].str.replace('2X6.4T','12T'))
df
Out[1]: 
                                       Type
0      AY12-AYY-AY-R800-900G-12T_18T-R6-v.A
1      AY12-AYY-AY-R800-900G-12T_18T-R6-v.A
2      AY12-AYY-AY-R800-900G-12T_18T-R6-v.A
3  AY12-AYY-AY-R800XD-900G-6.4T-R11-WOW-v.A
4  AY12-AYY-AY-R800XD-900G-6.4T-R11-WOW-v.A
```

Answer with `.where` which is like the "inverse" of mask:

```
 df['Type'] =  df['Type'].where(df['Type'].str.contains('WOW'),
                                df['Type'].str.replace('2X6.4T','12T'))
```

Comment: I had a brainfart. Output should be correct now :)